# Using Machanize to access password protected site

Tags: python, browser, authentication, mechanize

Im trying to get into a site using machanize but when i run my script its still just giving me the source for the homepage and not for the actual site

here is the code

```
from mechanize import Browser

USERNAME = "my username"
PASSWORD = "my pass"
LOGIN_PAGE = "https://ps.rsd.edu/public/"

browser = Browser()
browser.open( LOGIN_PAGE )


browser.select_form( nr=0 ) 
browser['pw'] = PASSWORD
response = browser.submit()
print response.read()
```

please help!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What do you expect to happen? It's printing the source because you are printing `response.read()`.

Comment: oh well im trying to get the source for the page it goes to when i enter the username and PW

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to enter username. It should be entered the same as password. Example:

```
from mechanize import Browser

USERNAME = "my username"
PASSWORD = "my pass"
LOGIN_PAGE = "https://ps.rsd.edu/public/"

browser = Browser()
browser.open( LOGIN_PAGE )


browser.select_form( nr=0 ) 
browser['account'] = USERNAME
browser['pw'] = PASSWORD
response = browser.submit()
print response.read()
```